# Running a nil block in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I was under the assumption that Objective-C's Blocks where just regular Cocoa objects. However, I found out, in the worst possible way, that there's slight difference: calling a nil block is not as innocuous as sending a message to `nil`.

This code crashes:

```
-(void) nilBlock{

    void (^thunk)(void) = ^void(void) {
        NSLog(@"Help me, I am blocked!");
    };

    NSLog(@"%@\n%@", [thunk class], thunk);

    thunk();
    thunk = nil;
    thunk();        // Bad access error

}
```

I thought that when you run a block, you're just sending some message to it and was expecting the last line to be a NOP.

What exactly is going on when you run a block?

Is there a way to avoid having to check if the block variable is `nil` (this seems like a flashback to Java...)?

Comment: Most languages take exception to dereferencing nil/null/NULL/0/nullptr, not just Java.

Comment: But @trojanfoe, you know Objective-C *usually* doesn't.

Comment: Only in one particular case: sending a message to an Objective-C object.  Try setting-up a function pointer to `NULL` and you'll get th e same results (function pointers being C-language, not Objective-C, just like blocks is a C-language feature).